# Can Uncrustify indent multi-line method call in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

I want my multi-line method call like this:

```
[self.markAsFinishedButton
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueButtonColor] andSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)]
    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But for now, it looks like this:

```
[self.markAsFinishedButton
setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueButtonColor] andSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)]
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

My `.uncrustify` file is here:
https://gist.github.com/nickcheng/d107d6f0f74ef381fb8e

BTW, I can get the right indent within a assignment by using this configuration like this:

```
_tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self
    action:@selector(controlButtonTapped)];
```

Could someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used these two (the second one is for message declarations):

```
align_oc_msg_colon_span = 10
align_oc_decl_colon = true
```

But I usually align code like this:

```
[self.markAsFinishedButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueButtonColor]
                                                              andSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)]
                                     forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```